# Multiple errors in my fragments after updating the support library to 27.0.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-support-library

After updating the support library from v-26.1.0 to v-27.0.0 Multiple errors in my fragments.

here is a list of some these errors:

> Error: Smart cast to 'Bundle' is impossible, because 'arguments' is a
> mutable property that could have been changed by this time.
>
> Error: 'onCreateView' overrides nothing
>
> Error: 'onViewCreated' overrides nothing
>
> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is View? but View was
> expected
>
> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Context? but Context
> was expected
>
> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but
> Context was expected
>
> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but
> Context was expected

from android studio's template for empty fragment.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (arguments != null) {
        mParam1 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        mParam2 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Please show example code which causes these errors. See [mcve] for tips about creating a new code example.

Answer (score 42):

The Root cause of all of these errors is that in support library v-27.0.0 `@Nullable` and `@NonNull`annotations have been added.
and since kotlin language is aware of nullability and has a different type for `Nullable` and `NonNull`, unlike Java.
without these annotations, the compiler has no way of differentiating between them, and Android studio was trying his best to infer the right type.

**TL;DR: change the types to rightly reflect the nullability status.**

---

> Error: Smart cast to 'Bundle' is impossible, because 'arguments' is a
>   mutable property that could have been changed by this time.

change `arguments.getString(ARG_NAME)` ==> `arguments?.getString(ARG_NAME) ?: ""`

---

> Error: 'onCreateView' overrides nothing

chane:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
```

==>

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
```

---

> Error: 'onViewCreated' overrides nothing

change:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

==>

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

---

> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Context? but Context
>   was expected

if context is passed as argument to method, just use the quick fix to replace `getContext()` with `getContext()?.let{}`
the same applies to the kotlin short version `context`.

else if is used to call some method replace `getContext().someMethod()` with `getContext()?.someMethod()`

the same applies to the kotlin short version `context?.someMethod()`.

---

> Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but
>   Context was expected

use the fix of the previous error.

Comment: Adding `?.let{}` to an fragment's activity does not allow me to use it as a method's argument. The error is `Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected`. Is there another to do this? Furthermore, when I try to access `cacheDir` for example, I get another one: `Smart cast to 'FragmentActivity' is impossible, because 'activity' is a property that has open or custom getter`. Still have to find how to resolve this one.

Comment: @StéphanePéchard This will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086296/smartcast-is-impossible-because-propery-has-open-or-custom-getter

Comment: @StéphanePéchard use "requireContext()" if you're in a fragment to get a non-null context - it'll throw an IllegalStateException if the context is null.

Comment: @humazed I am getting this problem in about more than 100 classes so isn't it a big problem?

Comment: errrrrrrrrr it's not just replacing 1 or 2 characters but bunch of them, a lot! and in some case it affects the flow of code. better downgrade to 26. seriously it's annoying. I really made big mistake by using kotlin and android studio i guess.

Answer (score 4):

For error message:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Bundle? but Bundle was expected
```

In class: `Fragment`, method: `onCreateView`

From

```
val arguments = SleepQualityFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments)
```

To

```
val arguments = SleepQualityFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
```