# Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected when updating the support library to 27.0.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I've updated my Kotlin project to use support library 27.0.0. When I try to get the Activity context in a Fragment I'm getting this error:

```
> Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple errors in my fragments after updating the support library to 27.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016853/multiple-errors-in-my-fragments-after-updating-the-support-library-to-27-0-0)

Answer (score 18):

It's safe to assume that `activity` or `context` is not null in any of the fragment's lifecycle methods (between `onAttach` and `onDetach)`. In this case

```
context!!
```

seems better because if it's null when it's definitely *NOT* supposed to be null, something is terribly wrong and you should just crash.

In asynchronous callbacks of course check for null.

> For me "!!" is never and option.

Then by all means abstract it away. This is what I did in my `BaseFragment` class:

```
val context: Context
    @JvmName("getContext2") 
    get() = getContext()!!
```

And then at use site:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    context // Context is *never* null here.
}

fun someCallbackMethod() {
    if (isAdded) {
        context // Context is also not null here.
    } else {
        // But it is null here.
    }
}
```

Unfounded null-checks everywhere are just as bad as the non-null assert operator.

This is equal to what would happen before support library 27 where nullability annotations were added. You could access `context` anywhere and it would crash if it were null and dereferenced.

**Update:** Recent support library introduced methods for this case:

- requireActivity(): Activity
- requireContext(): Context
- requireHost(): Object
- requireFragmentManager(): FragmentManager

The difference from my suggestion above is that these methods will throw `IllegalStateException` instead of `KotlinNullPointerException`.

Comment: Why getContext2 in this line @JvmName("getContext2") ?

Comment: @anivaler Good question! `val context` would get compiled to a `getContext()` method but there already is the original `getContext()` method. There's a conflict and you'd get a compile error. This way, when you override the generated method name, you can make it work. It can be anything else as long as it doesn't clash.