# kotlin 'onCreate' overrides nothing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using component development, in my common module BaseActivity.kt and BaseFragment.kt. The following problems occur when other modules inherit them

```
> D:\Android\OneDaily\module_main\src\main\java\com\boco\main\MainActivity.kt
> Error:(7, 24) Unresolved reference: base 
> Error:(9, 22) Unresolved reference: BaseActivity 
> Error:(21, 5) 'onCreate' overrides nothing
> Error:(17, 5) 'getLayoutRes' overrides nothing 
> Error:(22, 15) Unresolved reference: onCreate 
> Error:(27, 22) Unresolved reference: findViewById 
> Error:(42, 34) Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager
> D:\Android\OneDaily\module_main\src\main\java\com\boco\main\TimelineFragment.kt
> Error:(7, 24) Unresolved reference: base 
> Error:(10, 5) 'getLayoutRes' overrides nothing 
> Error:(9, 26) Unresolved reference: BaseFragment
> Error:(14, 5) 'onCreateView' overrides nothing 
> Error:(15, 22) Unresolved reference: onCreateView
```

BaseActivity.kt:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {  
    init {  
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)  
    }  
    abstract fun getLayoutRes(): Int  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)  
        setContentView(getLayoutRes())  
    }  
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBottomNav: BottomNavigationView

    private var mFragment1 = TimelineFragment() as Fragment
    private var mFragment2 = TimelineFragment() as Fragment
    private var mFragment3 = TimelineFragment() as Fragment

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_main
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

Comment: Would help to see your code.

Comment: please share your code snippet

Comment: I have try your given code with Android Studio 3.0 stable version and it's working fine. have you using same or other version of android studio ?

Comment: I am also using Android studio 3.0
But my MainActivity.kt is a baseActivity.kt that inherits from module. BaseActivity.kt inside the common module, MainActivity.kt inside module_main.I do not know if you are trying to do so

Comment: I'm seeing the same error after moving to support library version 27.0.0

Comment: `Unresolved reference: BaseActivity` – this might be related to a configuration issue with _Gradle_...

Comment: oh, thank you, really is the problem of Gradle. My common module did not
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016853/multiple-errors-in-my-fragments-after-updating-the-support-library-to-27-0-0

Answer (score 111):

It seems some functions have changed in the last update, 
just remove the '`?`' from the `Bundle`

Like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Which version can remove '?'

Comment: Also, if you are getting same error but in a fragment, remove '?' in fragmentManager: FragmentManager

Comment: This answer should be selected as the top-answer. Helped me out!

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio 3.3, appcompat-v7:28.0.0, compileSdkVersion 28

Comment: I'm using Android 3.5 and had the same problem the OP had but for onCreateDialog() not onCreate(). I was using the example from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#kotlin which had no ? after Bundle, but adding it fixed it. Thanks so much for the suggestion!

Comment: Had this problem but the solution was to add `?` in `Bundle`. I'm using AS: 4.0, Kotlin: 1.3.72, Gradle: 4.9

Comment: this works as well for override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface?) removing the nullable parameter to override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface)

Answer (score 60):

It can happen also in a Fragment class: I found the same issue for the method `onCreateView`; to avoid that, just remove the `?` from the `LayoutInflater` parameter,

Like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
```

Answer (score 11):

I have to add "?" when using appcompat-v7:27.1.1

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

and

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Worked for me for 27.0.2 as well.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise you will get "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState"

Answer (score 0):

Update function signatures or revert to compileSdk from 27 to 26

Answer (score -2):

i have fixed this problem. The because of it is you don't config you common module. Please add two lines code at your common module's build.gradle top:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

hope this can help you.