# isHermesEnabled overrides nothing in Kotlin

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-18

My project is using React 18 and Kotlin. The MainAplication.kt is returning an error that says:

> 'isHermesEnabled' overrides nothing

This is the Main Application file:

```
    class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

    private val mReactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = object : 
        DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
    override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG
    }

    override protected fun getPackages(): ArrayList<ReactPackage?> {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        val packages: ArrayList<ReactPackage?> = PackageList(this).getPackages()

        return packages
    }

    override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String {
        return "index.android"
    }

    override protected fun getJSBundleFile(): String? {
        return if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            super.getJSBundleFile()
        } else CodePush.getJSBundleFile()
    }

    override protected fun getJSIModulePackage(): JSIModulePackage? {
        return ReanimatedJSIModulePackage()
    }

    override protected fun isNewArchEnabled(): Boolean {
      return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
    }

    override protected fun isHermesEnabled(): Boolean {
      return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
    }
}
```

I tried the solutions from [kotlin onCreate overrides nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049471/kotlin-oncreate-overrides-nothing), but they did not work for me

I have the hermes variable set **true** in **build.gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [
enableHermes: true ]
```

and **gradle.properties**

```
hermesEnabled=true
```

What could I try next?

Comment: What are `Application` and `ReactApplication`? Does any of them have an `isHermesEnabled` method?

Comment: These are the packages => android.app.Application and com.facebook.react.ReactApplication. It should be possible to override isHermesEnabled from them since this is one of the changes to migrate to React 18. This is the link to the tool for migration reference
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.5&to=0.71.12

Comment: Does this error happen only in the IDE, or also when you gradle via the command line? Maybe the IDE just didn't pick up the new dependency. If gradle fails too on the command line, could you maybe provide a build scan? There might be a problem in the resolution of the react native dependency version

Comment: I run the app via the terminal. The command is react-native run-android. I've had this error for the other functions in this class, but I was able to fix it by adding ? to the type return. This one simply seems to not exist in the superclass as the message says. I ran out of ideas to fix this bug =(

Comment: If it really doesn't exist, did you try removing the overridden function entirely? If you get an error when you do this, what is it?

Comment: That was the solution. Not sure yet if Hermes is working with the old setup, but the app is running. This only happens in this project where I have Kotlin. I updated the Kotlin library to version 1.8, but it does not recognize the new react functions.